# GeoExt 4.0 Modern UI getExtent of a mapPanel

Tags: openlayers, geoext, ext-js

I am trying to port on Modern UI a project that was ok on ExtJs classic.

My problem is the following.
I use ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL, OpenLayers v4.6.5 and GeoExt 4.0

I set a TabPanel as a viewPort like in the modern layerlist example of GeoExt 4.0.
This TabPanel hold 2 panels : a Ext.Panel to hold the map and a Ext.grid.Grid for a layerList

```
mapComponent = Ext.create('GeoExt.component.Map', {  
 map: olMap  
});  
mapPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {  
 title: 'Map Panel'  
,id: 'theMapPanel'  
 ,layout: 'fit'  
,items: [mapComponent]  
});
```

My problem is the following:
Due to my personal database organisation (MySQL), in a way to get data for the layers, i need
width and height of the map view that is loaded inside its mapPanel.
How can I get these value ?

`mapComponent.getExtent();` returns bad values
`mapWidth = mapComponent.getWidth();` returns null
`mapHeight = mapComponent.getHeight();` returns null

Comment: In such cases one possible sulution is to go in the browser debugger and with inspector check which HTML element contains map. It usually has some unique CSS class, so you can get it by HTML DOM `getEelementsByClassName` method.

Comment: As welkl as the GeoExt methods you should be able to access the OpenL;ayers map and use its methods, for example  `mapComponent.getMap().getSize()`